# Using x,y coordinates and a value gathered in an Excel file, set these values in a raster with Python and GDAL

Tags: python, raster, gdal, coordinates, excel

I have an **Excel file** with X, Y coordinates and one  Altitude value for each coordinate. I have already gathered these values in a Python dict. Altitude, Lat, Long (see image)

[image]

Also, I have a **raster NetCDF file**, which I have alredy opened and transformed to an Array. All pixels of the array have an **NaN** value. So the output has to be an array with the altitude value in the coordinate pixels and NaN in the rest.

[image]

I want to set the **Altitude values** in the raster (array), exactly in the pixels that each coordinate (x,y) contains. To clarify, the raster is in EPSG:4326, so the pixel resolution is in degrees.

I have not found a suitable way in Python to get it. I am working with **Python 3.8**

Comment: Could you post an example X, Y value?  Is it the row and column of the raster (150, 2040)?  If you save the Excel file as a CSV then you can import csv in Python.  Otherwise you can use openpyxl to read the cells.  What file type of Raster do you have?

Comment: Does de sliced array have the shape (180, 360)?